# Vagrant Homestad en Amazon AWS

Tags: laravel, aws

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Laravel 5.6 en mi computadora de manera local con la maquina virtual homestad

Deseo publicar mi aplicación en una instancia de AWS pero deseo tener exactamente la misma configuración de mi maquina local en la instancia de AWS, como puedo hacer para pedir a AWS que tomar mi archivo de configuración de mi entorno local para crear la nueva instancia y no se me olvide instalar absolutamente nada.

Se que puedo configurar manualmente mi maquina pero deseo tener realmente el mismo entorno en local y en la nube.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para construirte el mismo entorno de trabajo, te espera un arduo trabajo manual...

Yo levantaría una nueva instancia de EC2, y empezaría por instalar los requerimientos de laravel homestead: virtualbox, vagrant...

Luego trataría de instalar la misma versión de laravel homestead en esa máquina.

Tu homestead.yml local te tendría que funcionar en la instancia EC2...

Sin embargo, tendrás que revisar bien el tema de ip's internas que tendrás, ya que la máquina de homestead tendrá su ip, la instancia de EC2 otra...al igual que hiciste en tu maquina local en tu fichero de hosts, pues en el entorno de aws, revisar security-group...

Otra opción más rápida sería probar laraedit, (desconozco si tienes conocimientos de docker). Pero laraedit es un contenedor con laravel homestead (https://github.com/laraedit/laraedit-docker)

Si tu entorno local hubieras trabajado con docker, esto se hubiese simplificado mucho... Existen contenedores muy buenos para trabajar con laravel y levantar un servidor web para él...

Ánimo! Suerte!